# FileWriter doesnt create new file

Tags: java, filewriter, bufferedwriter

I have written a code to convert a text file to csv format. The items in text file are separated with tab. There is no error in the code and it runs successfully, yet no new csv file is created. Please Help!
Here is my code:

```
    package prediction.convert;

    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.BufferedWriter;
    import java.io.FileReader;
    import java.io.FileWriter;
    import java.io.IOException;

    public class SongDataConvert {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("data/song_data.txt"));
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("data/song_data.csv"));

    String line;
    while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
        String[] values = line.split("\\t", -1);
        bw.write(values[0] + "," + values[1] + "," + values[2] + "\n"); 
    }

    br.close();
    bw.close();

}

}
```

Comment: works for me, try to manually flush the bufferedWriter before closing it (`bw.flush();`) Closing would flush it anyway though

Comment: Are you still using Java 6-?

Comment: No using Java 8 now!